# Google algorithm penalty & reconsideration request

Tags: seo, google-search-console, penalty, negative-seo

There is no any manuel penalty message on my Webmaster Tools > manual actions tab.

But, my visitors count decrease 10.000 to 1.000 in last 3 years.
All seo-check services says my site is OK: W3C standarts, mobile site, unique content, site speed, etc.

But especially in last 6 month, I fell from 1st page to 6th page on search results.

This week I also will use disavow file for harmful backlinks.

Do you also suggest me to use a Google reconsideration request or is it just for manuel penalties, which are seen in Webmaster Tools / manuel actions tab?

Comment: Do you have fresh content?

Comment: everyday i add 6 article(news), and about 50 images. i mean: its really really fresh..

Comment: I didn't think you could file a reconsideration request any longer if you have no manual actions showing in Google WMT? The link to the reconsideration request form only can only be accessed via this page in WMT.

Comment: It sounds like you need to update your SEO strategy. This is a slow drop and so it cannot be a penalty but rather a story of not changing with the times and properly re-evaluating how your work is perceived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not like a manual penalty. Your page fell from 1st page to 6th page in last three years ?

If your page is in 1st page and click through rate is very low, then your website position will be decreased by Google, thinking that your page has no value to be there and has not got enough clicks to remain in the same place forever.

So think like this, if your page is indexed in top, Google will be calculating your click through rate and based on this they make changes in your website appearance in Google results.

It is better not to re-consider because your website will be evaluated as new one.

Remain with this position and try to boost your listing by adding relevant blog containing your keyword rich content. Analyse other websites above you and see what they have different from you. This can definitely help you in understanding and solving this issue.